# Rich text not working on inspector but works on built game

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine

I have an UI Text summing up all actions in the game and I managed to get colors whether the name is ours, is in our team or is in the ennemy team. To try it out, I build a game and launch another from Unity, but the Rich Text doesn't seem to work properly here and I don't know why :

`Feed
<color=green>clientt</color> has slain <color=red>cli</color>`
This is what is written in the TextScript

[image: description]

Sorry for the bad editing but as you can see the text is colored but Unity doesn't show it.
The fact is that when I disable rich text from the CheckBox see what happens : 
[image]

I would be glad if you knew what is going on,
thanks in advance

Edit : Without editing anything when launching the game again it works I don't know why honestly, look :

[image]

Comment: Please copy and post the text in your question too.

Comment: @Programmer done

Comment: That's weird. It works on my side. Post the whole `Text` component screenshot. I can only see half of it now. I want to compare the settings with mine. Also, mention your Unity version

Comment: @Programmer I honestly don't get anything of what is going on :/

Comment: Well it works now, right? Your last screenshot shows that it works

Comment: It's working like half of the time I don't know. If the problem still occurs I'll tell

Comment: No problem it should be working **always** otherwise restart Unity